# Bear not created correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm building my first MEAN stack app using [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) Scotch article.

I've gotten to the point where I'm sending `POST` requests to my `localhost` to create new bears (the model) via Postman.

The problem is that when I send a request to see all the bears I get back the following:

```json
[
  {"_id":"589f6ecc734d1d56393c9444","name":"Klaux"},   
  {"_id":"589f6f924af04a03d8870dea","__v":0}
]
```

The first object in the array was an example I created in my MongoDB manually when I created a new `document`. As mentioned above when I send a request for creation via Postman it isn't created correctly (the second object in the array.)

Here's the code that sends the request:

```js
// /api/bears
router.route('/bears')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      console.log('Bears',bears);
            res.json(bears);
    });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
    bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

    // save the bear and check for errors
    bear.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });
});

app.use('/api', router);
```

And the database collection looks like this:

[image: MongoDB mLab]

So why isn't the record being created correctly?

**EDIT**

The bear model looks like this:

```js
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');

var BearSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

Comment: What's your bear model like?

Comment: @LuisDiegoHernández See my edit

Answer (score 0):

This was actually asked answered in the comments section at the bottom of the article. 
Here's a summary:

When sending from `Postman` the option of `x-www-form-urlencoded` shouldn't be set.
Instead it should be set to `raw` and passed as `JSON`. See the screenshot below:

[image]